# Check if product type is grouped, without loading whole product

Tags: magento2, resource-model, product-type

I want to check whether a certain product is of type 'grouped' or something else. And, i need to do this without loading the whole product.

Now for other attributes the code below seems to work perfectly well.

```
$productResource = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action');
$uom = $productResource->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'uom', $storeId);
```

But somehow this fails:

```
$type = $productResource->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'type_id', $storeId);
```

$type is always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type_id is not an eav attribute.
without gathering the whole model, you can do it through raw SQL query(it is the fastest solution I guess)

```
SELECT type_id FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE entity_id=Your_Product_Id
```

Comment: Ah, that sounds like a reason for not being able to retrieve it via the getAttributeRawValue

Comment: The thing is, im handling many many products, and just some of them are grouped. And, if so, i have to do something with the underlying childs. So i was really hoping to find a solution that doesn't involve a database call for every product.

Comment: You can do only one query like
`SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE type_id="grouped"`

just save result of this query and compare products ids in PHP. If product id is in result(this product is grouped) then do some logic

Comment: I'll go for the one query setup. And next, i'm going to create an additional attribute which i'm going to set to true, if an item is a grouped item.